# Reading SPSS (.sav) dataset into R with haven and getting errors

Tags: r, spss

I'm trying to load an SPSS data set (.sav) into R using the Haven package and can't get it to work.

I'm running
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

on OS 10.15.7

I've loaded Haven:

```
install.packages('haven', repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Loaded all of the dependencies, and "install[ed] from sources the packages which need compilation."

Got lots of warnings like this one:

```
 Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘diffobj’ had non-zero exit status
```

Tried to load the file using this:

```
df <- read_spss('file.sav')
```

also tried

```
df <- read_sav('file.sav')
```

get this error:

```
Error in read_sav("file.sav") : 
  could not find function "read_sav"
```

At one point it looked like I was missing a package called Pillar, so I added that (but it still didn't work). Then I added the bit of code to downloading Haven about dependencies so figured that should resolve that.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `install.packages('diffobj')`

Comment: Is there any way the issue could have to do with running an older version of r studio?

Comment: It is a old R version.  I would update the R version.  Current version is R 4.1.0

Comment: Updating R to 4.1.0 seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could install the additional packages needed.  Based on the OP's post, the `R version` is old.  The current version is `R 4.1.0`.  Would recommend to update the `R` and then install

```
install.packages('diffobj')
```

Comment: Even installing 'diffobj' resulted in the same error: 

```Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘diffobj’ had non-zero exit status```

Comment: Updating R to 4.1.0 seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!